# how to create a checkboxlist in ASP.Net MVC using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkboxlist

I want to generate dynamic checkboxes on the basis of selected value of dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Fromsource, new SelectList(Model.Fromsource, "Value", "Key"), "---Select---", new
                    {

                    })
@Html.CheckBox("Tosource", false, new { @class = "dropdown" })
<script>
  $("#Fromsource").change(function () {
            var urlSource = '@Url.Action("FillToSource", "PublishPost")';
            var fromsouyrcetype = $(this).val();
            if (fromsouyrcetype != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlSource,
                    method: "GET",
                    data: {
                        "sourceType": fromsouyrcetype
                    },
                    success: function (result) {

                        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                            //what to write here?
                           //value.name = name of the checkbox
                          //value.id = value of the checkbox
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {


            }

        });</script>
```

`value.id` and `value.name` are the values which i want to fill for checkbox as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Not clear what your wanting to do. - `$('#Tosource').empty();` makes no sense (it clears the child elements of the element and a checkbox does not have any). Are you wanting to create multiple checkboxes?

Comment: It's not acceptable to have List<bool> instrad of your FromSource? Initially, one bool in the model reprendents checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to dynamically create checkboxes based on the result that you are getting from server (query performed each time that dropdown value changed):

```
<div id="checkboxContainer"></div>
<script>
  $("#Fromsource").change(function () {
            var urlSource = '@Url.Action("FillToSource", "PublishPost")';
            var fromsouyrcetype = $(this).val();
            if (fromsouyrcetype != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlSource,
                    method: "GET",
                    data: {
                        "sourceType": fromsouyrcetype
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                            $('#checkboxContainer').empty();
                            var content;
                            $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                                content += '<input type="checkbox" name="'+ value.name +'" id="'+value.id+'"/>'
                            });
                            $('#checkboxContainer').html(content);
                        }
                });
            } else {
                $('#checkboxContainer').empty();

            }

        });</script>
```